# check for duplicate records in a sql server table using c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a table in SQL server that contains string data on two columns. I also have a "add" method in c# , but I don't what to be able to add the same data on the two columns again.For example in the table I have data similar to this:

```
code first_name last_name 
 1     john       smith
 2     mike       croft
```

I don't want to have the possibility to add john smith or mike croft again even if the code is different. I'm kind of new to c# so if someone could give me a simple answer in a code I would really appreciate it.

P.S. The code is the primary key , and I have other columns as well.

This is the code i have :

```
    Form1 obj = (Form1)Application.OpenForms["Form1"];

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@" Data Source=HOME-D2CADC8D4F\SQL;Initial Catalog=motociclete;Integrated Security=True");
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        pictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

        byte[] pic_arr = new byte[ms.Length];
        ms.Position = 0;
        ms.Read(pic_arr, 0, pic_arr.Length);

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into motociclete(firma,model,poza,pret,anf,greutate,caprez,putere,garantie,stoc) values (@firma,@model,@poza,@pret,@anf,@greutate,@caprez,@putere,@garantie,@stoc)",cn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firma", textBox3.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@model", textBox10.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@poza", pic_arr);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pret", textBox7.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@anf", textBox4.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@greutate", textBox9.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@caprez", textBox5.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@putere", textBox8.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@garantie", textBox6.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stoc", textBox2.Text);

        cn.Open();


        try
        {
            int rez = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (rez > 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Adaugare reusita ");


            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);


        }
        finally {
            cn.Close();
            obj.loaddata();
            this.Close();

        }



    }




}
```

I don't want to be able to add two records with the same "firma" and "model".But it's ok if one of them repeats itself.
I hope the code helps.

Comment: Can you show us what code you have so far?

Comment: I'd probably start by putting a `UNIQUE INDEX` on `(first_name, last_name)`

Comment: What data access technology will you be using? I think service stack's ormlite is easy to use and powerful.

Comment: I'm goint to be a pedant and suggest a unique CONSTRAINT rather than index.  To me at least a constraint indicates a feature of the data (or schema) whereas an index indicates a performance twiddle.   The end result is the same of course.

Comment: How are you "adding" new items to the database with C#? Are you using System.Data.SqlClient? LINQ to SQL?

Comment: I use c#.Yes I am using System.Data.SqlClient

Comment: If I put a UNIQUE INDEX on (first_name, last_name) dosen't that mean that i can't have two records with the same first_name even if the last_name is different ?

Comment: @LoztInSpace    I don't fully understand what you mean.Could you explain to me how to do that constraint thing step-by-step? Thanks.

Comment: alter table A add constraint NAME_UNIQUE unique (first_name, last_name)

The idea is that you are saying something about your data not making an index for performance reasons.  It's a subtle difference.

To answer your Q above - you can have tons of Johns and Mikes, loads of Smiths and Crofts provided any pair appear only once in the table - i.e. they are UNIQUE!

Answer (score 1):

I did it by adding a CONSTRAINT in SQL. It works now. If anyone has a similar problem this is the code I wrote in SQL:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[motociclete]
ADD CONSTRAINT uniq UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([firma],[model])
```

Here is a link to a youtube video that helped me:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iS-KEu0pwXI

Answer (score 0):

> Here is check for duplicate record first u want to select if txt
>   values have in sql so don't insert otherwise insert

```
bool readerHasRows = false; // <-- Initialize bool here for later use

                        string firma= txt_friema.Text;
                        string model= txt_model.Text;

                        //string color_na = textBox3.Text;
                        string commandQuery = "SELECT firma,model FROM motociclete WHERE firma = @firma or model=@model";
                        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(commandQuery, con))
                        {
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firma", txt_friema.Text);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@model", txt_model.Text);


                            using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                            {
                                // bool initialized above is set here
                                readerHasRows = (reader != null && reader.HasRows);
                            }
                        }

                        if (readerHasRows)
                        {

                            MessageBox.Show("Already Exists!!");


                        }

                      else
                        {
                           //your insertion qrocedure  
                        }
```

Hope You Liked It
Thanks